# getUserMedia api is not able to capture audio along with video from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, video, google-chrome-extension

I am using getUserMedia api to capture screen and record audio (both together) from chrome extension. The api captures the screen, records the video but doesn't capture the audio.

Chrome version: 55

Any reason why the audio is not being captured. Is there any limitation with the api or do we need to use any other api to capture video+audio?
Please find the code snippet below. (below code is present in background.js)

(tried passing the constraints as audio: true, video: true, but this didnt work. it was  throwing an error.(Error - getUserMedia() failed: [object NavigatorUserMediaError]))

```
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(['screen','audio'],
    function onAccessApproved(id) {     

    const constraints = { "video": {
             mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',       
                chromeMediaSourceId: id,        
                minWidth: 1280,
                minHeight: 720,                 
                maxWidth:1280,
                maxHeight:720
            }
            }, "audio" : {
             mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',       
            chromeMediaSourceId: id}} };                    

 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(gotMedia).catch(e => { console.error('getUserMedia() failed: ' + e); 
});

function gotMedia(stream) {

  theStream = stream;
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  video.srcObject = stream;

  try {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType : "video/webm"});
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder: ' + e);
    return;
  }

  theRecorder = recorder;
  recorder.ondataavailable = 
      (event) => { recordedChunks.push(event.data); };
  recorder.start(100);


  stream.getVideoTracks()[0].onended = function () {
        download();
    };
}   


function download() {


  theRecorder.stop();
  theStream.getTracks().forEach(track => { track.stop(); });

  var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {type: "video/webm"});
  var url =  URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style = "display: none";
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'test.webm';
  a.click();
  // setTimeout() here is needed for Firefox.
  setTimeout(function() { URL.revokeObjectURL(url); }, 100); 
}
```

Comment: _"it was throwing an error."_ What is the error?

Comment: error: getUserMedia() failed: [object NavigatorUserMediaError]

Comment: Is protocol `https:`?

Comment: yes, protocol is https

Comment: Is `.play()` called? Is `gotMedia` defined within scope of `onAccessApproved`?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [webRTC Experiment's page](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/#why-screen-fails) about screen sharing,

> **Why Screen Sharing Fails?**
>   [...]
>   2. On chrome, you requested audio-stream alongwith 'chromeMediaSource' – it is not permitted on chrome.

So it is not permitted.

You could try to make a parallel request for audio only, then merge both streams with [`MediaStream.addTrack()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/addTrack), though I didn't tested it.

`videoStream.addTrack(audioStream.getAudioTracks()[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the top Google result for "NavigatorUserMediaError mediaRecorder" I want to suggest too that if anyone else is getting that error message, on Android Chrome for example, it might have to do with security certificates. MediaRecorder cannot access a mobile device's mic or camera unless the site has an SSL certificate and the url is HTTPS.

You can request HTTPS the same way Google does in its simple.info/mr example's [code](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/getusermedia/record/js/main.js):

```
// window.isSecureContext could be used for Chrome
var isSecureOrigin = location.protocol === 'https:' ||
location.hostname === 'localhost';
if (!isSecureOrigin) {
  alert('getUserMedia() must be run from a secure origin: HTTPS or localhost.' +
    '\n\nChanging protocol to HTTPS');
  location.protocol = 'HTTPS';
}
```

But you will also need to ensure the site has an SSL certificate to reference. On HostGator this costs about $30/yr, but GitHub.io offers it for free if you're just looking to test some code. You can also supposedly run the files locally and it won't require any security certificates, but I have not tested that yet.